# Chrome bug or jQuery bug?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Why does the following code do as expected ( resizes drop down list based on selection ) on IE 7 and FF 15.0.1 but always ends up size 1 on Chrome 23.0.1271.91?

I've tried to add console.log and actually see what is happening, and it seems that the resize function is firing twice in Chrome, but being a newbie at jQuery, I'm not sure I quite understand passing objects yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>          
  <script type="text/javascript">                                         

   var vt = new Array('1','2','3','4','5');
   var x = 1;

   function addopts(ddl) {
       console.log(ddl);
       for ( var i = 0; i < vt.length; i++ ) {
           var v = i * x;
           $(ddl).append("<option value='" + v + "'>" + v + "</option>");
       }
       console.debug(ddl);

       vt.push(x);
       x++; // our list changes
   }

   function resize(ddl) {

       console.log(ddl);

       ddl.size = $(ddl).val();
       $(ddl).empty();  // in case our list needs to change completely
       console.log(ddl);

       addopts(ddl);
       console.log(ddl);
   }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
        console.log(this);
        $('#group').change(function() {
            console.log(this);
            resize(this);
        });
    });

  </script>                                                               

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
     <select id='group' size='1'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
     </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

↪ [View this code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVqML/)

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: not sure expected result, I jsut fiddled it, and it looks funky even in FF17

Comment: It seems to work fine in Chrome 25.0.1323.1 -- if I understand what it's supposed to do: the element changes to the size you pick. Also the same in FF17.

Comment: Confirmed, I have Chrome 23 and was having the same issue. checking for nightly build now

Comment: Yes, I have reproduced the issue too. And this is not a `jQuery` issue, since binding the event directly on the DOM via `document.getElementById('group').onchange = function(e) { ... };` produces the same bug.

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 23 on the Mac

Comment: After some investigations (I am on Windows 7), it is the size change of the ddl which triggers the second change event. Moreover on Chrome, it seems that only 2 family of values applies : `size`= `0` and `1` sets a standard ddl as `size >= 2` makes a list with 4 elements. Strange isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed appear to be an issue with Chrome in 2 respects. After much testing I found the following problems in **BOTH** Chrome 23 and 24

1. jQuery's .change && .on("change" **as well as** JavaScripts .onchange function does indeed fire twice only in chrome

   - I have no answer for this, tho I have found a workaround I will post below
2. Chrome does not appear to have *odd* numbered sizes available for rendering select boxes.

   - Chrome appears to resize to the nearest even number ( i think i noted it rounds up ) in order to re-render the select box.
   - ***UPDATE*** Further testing has shown (at least in ver 24) that this rendering to even numbers only issue, ONLY applies to sizes 0 through 4!

The Workaround I mentioned is as simple as throwing in a timer in order to set the select to a new instance, thus negating the double fire. Forgive me if my terminology sux, point is, it helps chrome to fire only once on change and does not affect other browsers (so far as i have found)

I also took the liberty of rewriting your code a little, just simply to make it easier for me to read (your code seemed a bit "extended")

## Example jsFiddle

> **Script** i used

```
var vt = new Array('1','2','3','4','5'),
    x = 1;

//  Since jQuery 1.1+ (i think) you no longer need the long written `$(document).ready`.
//  Now you can do the same thing with the short-hand below
$(function() {
    //  The selector you get. The .on() function is relativly new to jQuery and simply provides an easy way to bind events to elements
    //  You can also use .off to unbind a function to an element, for instance, i could wrap the inner function in a func named `reSize`
    //      and then add it and remove it with:
    //          - To add event: $("#group").on("change", reSize)
    //          - To remove event: $("#group").off("change", reSize)
    $("#group").on("change", function(e) {
        //  I create a variable of $(this) simply to pass it to the Timer function
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() { //  basic JavaScript here
            //  Prop is also kind of new to jQuery. You used to just use `.attr()`, but now jQuery distinguishes between Attributes and Properties
            //  Since "size" is a Property of the select element, I use .prop to get/set the value
            //      In this case I'm of course setting the size to the current value
            //  One nice feature of jQuery you'll see here is "chaining"
            //      as you notice, i added the `.empty` to the end, since each jquery function generally returns the element object you started with
            //          Of course, had I only been GETting the value of size, this would not be the case
            $this.prop("size", $this.val()).empty();
            for (i=0;i<vt.length;i++) { //  basic JavaScript here
                var v = i*x;    //  your initial setup
                //  Here I replaced the append function you had with much more readable code.
                //  There are several ways to do this in jQuery, however
                //      fragmented Strings are not ever really suggested
                //  This could have also been written:
                //      $this.append($("<option />", { text: v, value: v }));
                $this.append($("<option />").val(v).text(v));
            }
            vt.push(x); //  more basic JavaScript
            x++;
            //      The following was used for debugging on the fiddle
            console.log(x)
            $("#selectSize").text($this.prop("size"));
        });
    });
})
```

#### Some Helpful **jQuery** Links

- [StackOverflow's NFO on jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) (Lot of good examples)
- [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
- [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> And just to help you out. If you want it in an independent function again, the following is the exact same as the above, except the function is separate and therefor applicable to any select.

```
var vt = new Array('1','2','3','4','5'),
    x = 1;

function reSizeSelect(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.prop("size", $this.val()).empty();
        for (i=0;i<vt.length;i++) {
            var v = i*x;
            $this.append($("<option />").val(v).text(v));
        }
        vt.push(x);
        x++;
        console.log(x)
        $("#selectSize").text($this.prop("size"));
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#group").on("change", reSizeSelect);
})
```

Comment: Thanks SpYk3HH, that will work for me. My page actually consists of 5 drop down boxes A, B, C, D, E, and I needed them to interact with each other in somewhat unusual ways. B and D depend on value of A, C depends on B, etc... So after I figure your "compacted" code out, I'll probably split it back into separate functions to work with objects other than $this. Not sure how to accept/upvote your answer yet, so please bear with me. New to jQuery, new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: NP, glad I could help and welcome to SO. Gimmie a few mins and I'll edit my answer to show line by line comments of what I'm doing and hopefully help you better understand jQuery

Comment: @JohnSmith Updated my answer with more detail and explination of the jQuery. Enjoy! Oh, and I think you have to reach a certain reputation before you can upvote.